# Aws code build not using latest commit on pull request merge

Tags: github, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS CodeBuild to build a JAR file whenever a pull request is merged into the master branch.
I have configured the source provider to be github, source version to be the master branch and Event type to be PULL_REQUEST_MERGED. However, when I merge a feature branch into master, CodeBuild uses the latest commit from the feature branch instead of the latest commit from the master branch.

For example, the current state of the master branch is A -> B -> C, and the feature branch is A -> B -> D -> E. After merging, the master branch will be A -> B -> C -> F. CodeBuild is using commit E to build the JAR file instead of commit F from the master branch. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  Running into the same issue

Comment: no @Parker, I haven't found a solution.

Comment: So for me, this was due to having a release  branch with the same name as a branch. I have a development branch named `PHP7.4` and I also have a release branch named `release/PHP7.4`. CodeBuild pulled the release instead of the actual branch name I specified. Weird since the release branch is prefixed with `release` but this was my issue. Very frustrating.